# What is flicker ball in cricket?

Tags: cricket, terminology

[Harbajan Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbhajan_Singh) has been described as bowling a variation called a "flicker". What is this variation, and how to bowl it? (I know it's different from the [carrom ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrom_ball) or the [flipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipper_(cricket))).

Answer (score 1):

Flicker is a kind of variation used by off-spinner, they use the middle finger to flick the ball, as well flight the ball so that it goes flat after pitching it isn’t used by many bowlers as it is ineffective

Answer (score -1):

Flicker Ball is just a variation or technique use by bowler to distract the batsman. Bowl did't spin much after pitching.